# How to print "Spring" if in month is in Jan-June? Otherwise "Fall"?

Tags: conditionals

I teach classes and in my notes I have "Fall 2015" during fall semester and "Spring 2016" during Spring semester. I can use

```
\the\year
```

for the year. But is there something like

```
\the\season
```

for Fall and Spring? And if so, how can I customize which months define the semester?

Comment: `year` is a count register, but `season` is a range of counter values actually

Comment: Of course, all this breaks down if you want to get ahead of things and produce some notes for spring term in December, for instance. Seems that something like `\newcommand\term{Spring 2015}` is simple and easily changed for next term. Sometimes over-automation creates more work than it alleviates.

Answer (score 15):

Without any extra package and providing support for `northern` or `southern` hemisphere:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifnorthernhemisphere
\northernhemispheretrue

\newcommand{\season}{%
  \ifnorthernhemisphere
  \ifcase\month
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Winter
  \fi
  \else
  \ifcase\month
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Summer
  \fi
  \fi
}



\begin{document}
Northern hemisphere

\the\month\ \season

\month=5
\the\month\ \season

\month=9
\the\month\ \season

Southern hemisphere

\month=2
\northernhemispherefalse
\the\month\ \season


\month=5
\the\month\ \season

\month=9
\the\month\ \season

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Here's a variant with optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifnorthernhemisphere
\northernhemispheretrue

\newcommand{\season}[1][\month]{%
  \ifnorthernhemisphere
  \ifcase#1
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Winter
  \fi
  \else
  \ifcase#1
  \or Summer
  \or Summer
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Fall
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Winter
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Spring
  \or Summer
  \fi
  \fi
}



\begin{document}
Northern hemisphere

\season


\season[5]


\season[9]

Southern hemisphere


\northernhemispherefalse
\season

\season[5]

\season[9]

\end{document}
```

**Another version -- with `xparse` and `expl3` features:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_default_spring_semester_seq
\seq_new:N \g_default_fall_semester_seq

\seq_new:N \g_spring_semester_seq
\seq_new:N \g_fall_semester_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_default_spring_semester_seq {1,2,3,4,5,6}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetSpringSemesterMonths}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_spring_semester_seq {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetFallSemesterMonths}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_fall_semester_seq {#1}
}

\SetSpringSemesterMonths{1,2,3,4,5,6}
\SetFallSemesterMonths{7,8,9,10,11,12}

\NewDocumentCommand{\season}{}{%
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_spring_semester_seq 
  {\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \g_default_spring_semester_seq}
  {\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \g_spring_semester_seq}
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_fall_semester_seq {\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_seq \g_default_fall_semester_seq}
  {\seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_seq \g_fall_semester_seq}
  \seq_if_in:NVTF \l_tmpa_seq {\month} {
    Spring%
  }{%
    \seq_if_in:NVTF \l_tmpb_seq {\month} {%
      Fall%
    }{}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\season

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Now with `shell-escape` and using https://pleasefeedthegeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/geolocation-lookups-in-linux-ubuntu/ you can automate it ;-) `/me ducks`

Comment: @Rmano: Well, let us not to be sophisticated ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ifnum\month<7
Spring
\else
Fall
\fi

\month=11
\ifnum\month<7
Spring
\else
Fall
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does assume that there's only Spring or Fall? ;-)

Comment: This is what the OP ask for :-)

Comment: Oh my bad, it's in the title :/

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** Crazier code, no properties list! `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_season_clist
\bool_new:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool

\NewDocumentCommand { \getseason } { m } {
   \clist_item:Nn \g_season_clist {
    \int_mod:nn {
      \int_div_round:nn { #1 - 1 } { 3 } + \bool_if:NTF \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool { 3 } { 1 } 
    } { 4 } + 1
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \setseasons } { m } {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_season_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \northenhemisphere } { } {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \southernhemisphere } { } {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setseasons{Spring,Summer,Fall,Winter}

\northenhemisphere
In the Northen Hemisphere, we have \getseason{\month}.

\southernhemisphere
In the Southern Hemisphere, we have \getseason{\month}.

\end{document}
```

---

**Original attempt:** Crazy code ahead! `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_season_clist
\prop_new:N \g_season_prop

\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 12 } { 4 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 1 } { 4 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 2 } { 4 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 3 } { 1 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 4 } { 1 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 5 } { 1 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 6 } { 2 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 7 } { 2 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 8 } { 2 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 9 } { 3 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 10 } { 3 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_season_prop { 11 } { 3 }

\bool_new:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool

\NewDocumentCommand { \getseason } { m } {
   \clist_item:Nn \g_season_clist {
    \int_mod:nn {
      \prop_item:Nn \g_season_prop { #1 } + \bool_if:NTF \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool { 3 } { 1 } 
    } { 4 } + 1
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \setseasons } { m } {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_season_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \northenhemisphere } { } {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \southernhemisphere } { } {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_season_northenhemisphere_bool
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setseasons{Spring,Summer,Fall,Winter}

\northenhemisphere
In the Northen Hemisphere, we have \getseason{\month}.

\southernhemisphere
In the Southern Hemisphere, we have \getseason{\month}.

\end{document}
```

---

The output:

[image: Quack]

One could add a `babel` hook to setup seasons names according to the current language or even use `datetime` to format any date, like, for example, `\season\today`. Hope it helps! `:)`

Comment: *I should be writing my thesis instead, I should be writing my thesis instead, I should be writing my thesis instead, I should be writing my thesis instead...*

Comment: Ah, the solution from the southern hemisphere :-P

Comment: @Christian: ducks *do* understand about seasons. `:)`

Comment: And Black Foresters know how to upvote ... and now back to your thesis :-P

Comment: The variables should be global, in my opinion.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26774875#26774875

Comment: @egreg: thanks, I fixed the code (hopefully towards the correct way). `:)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: that's mean. `:)`

Comment: @Christian: crazier code provided. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: I can't upvote again ;-)

Answer (score 8):

What about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

The term now is: \ifthenelse{\month<6}{Spring}{Fall} 

\end{document}
```

With the [`ifthen` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ifthen.pdf) you can build quite complex conditional text.

Obviously you have to adapt it to your case, but you can nest `\ifthenelse` and even use `\month` or `\day` in it to fine-tune the result.

```
The term now is: \ifthenelse{\month<9}{%
    \ifthenelse{\month<6}{Spring}{Summer}}%
    {Fall}
```

(this last suppose Spring term for Jan to May, Fall from Sep to Dec, and the rest Summer. YMMV)

Comment: The problem is that the spring occurs in different months in North/South hemisphere.

Comment: @Sigur: That's hard to track from `LaTeX` unless there are `geolocation` tools in LaTeX ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And what about TeX? You used TeX primitives in your answer, this has no connection to LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet: Fair point. I know, you find `LaTeX` horrible, especially mixing `TeX` and `LaTeX`, but in this case I found `TeX` much simpler. If I would kick out the `LaTeX` specific commands it would work with `TeX` too, I suppose

Comment: The title only asks for this two mode output, but your test should be `month<7`.

Answer (score 1):

A `biblatex` solution, for when there are multiple or archival items.

[image: season]

Treating the season as part of the publication (meta)data.

Localisation can also come into play. (Note that not all `babel`/`polyglossia` languages define `season`-related strings (yet).)

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@misc{notesset1,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 1}, 
  date = {2020-23},
    }
% season (21=spring, 22=summer, 23=autumn, 24=winter)

@misc{notesset2,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 2}, 
  date = {2021-21},
    }

@misc{notesset3,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 3}, 
  date = {2021-22},
    }   

@misc{notesset4,
  title = {Lektur 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {ngerman},
%  language={langgerman},
    }   


@misc{notesset5,
  title = {Διάλεξη 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {greek},
  language={langgreek},
    }   

@misc{notesset5a,
  title = {Conferenza 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {italian},
  language={langitalian},
    }   

\end{filecontents*}




\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}
          [Color=DarkGreen ,
          ]{Noto Serif}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
dateabbrev=false,% full name of season
language=autocite,%pick up the langid language, for citations
autolang=other,%wrap with otherlanguage environment and translate date-related names according to the langid
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareListFormat{language}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}\addcolon}{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasonall}
{}
{\textmd{\printlist{language}}
\printfield{title}\addcomma\addspace\printdate}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasontitle}
{}
{\printfield{title}
}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseason}
{}
{\printdate}
{}
{}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{greek}{%
  spring    = {άνοιξη},
  summer  = {καλοκαίρι},
  autumn   = {φθινόπωρο},
  winter     = {χειμώνας},
  langgreek = {Ελληνικά},
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  spring    = {primavera},
  summer  = {estate},
  autumn   = {autunno},
  winter     = {inverno},
  langitalian = {italiano},
}




%-----------------------------

\title{\citeseasontitle{notesset1}}
\author{}
\date{\citeseason{notesset1}}
%------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Overview}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset1}} covers introductory material.
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset2}} advances to the next topic.
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset3}} covers the extended course.
\item German: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset4}} is the xyz version. 
\item Greek: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset5}} is the abc version. 
\item Italian: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset5a}} is the abc version. 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

*Automating*

A more generalised solution, using a custom code number.

`Biber` can do the four seasons using the `date` field when the month is set to certain values:

```
  my %
    seasons = ( 21 => 'spring',
                  22 => 'summer',
                  23 => 'autumn',
                  24 => 'winter' );
                  
...\texlive\2020
\texmf-dist
\source
\bibtex
\biber
\biblatex-biber.tar
\biblatex-biber
\biblatex-biber-2.15
\lib
\Biber
\Date                  
format.pm
```

Extending that idea, but using instead a custom field (`term`) processed via macros at `Biblatex`/`Latex`-level, University Terms and Court Terms can be done:

[image: Example formats]

Illustrating the use of the `xsv` field type and associated `\forcsvfield` command,  allowing customised sequencing of fields on a per-bibentry basis (and the expl3 split function); and formatting hooks within the citation command, allowing the changing of the citation format  mid-document; and bibstrings for localisation. Plus an example of using a field as an input argument to arbitrary code using `\usefield` (here, an image name).

An exercise in what could be done.

Use-case: sets or compendia, or other bulk volumes?

Terms can always be keyed in manually if there are only a few, or the `issue` field of `@article` could be used.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@misc{notesset1,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 1}, 
  date = {2020-23},
    }
% season (21=spring, 22=summer, 23=autumn, 24=winter)

@misc{notesset2,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 2}, 
  date = {2021-21},
    }

@misc{notesset3,
  title = {Lecture Notes Set 3}, 
  date = {2021-22},
    }   

@misc{notesset4,
  title = {Lektur 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {ngerman},
%  language={langgerman},
    }   


@misc{notesset5,
  title = {Διάλεξη 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {greek},
  language={langgreek},
    }   

@misc{notesset5a,
  title = {Conferenza 1}, 
  date = {2021-22},
  langid = {italian},
  language={langitalian},
    }   
@misc{testutag,
  title = {Test Titleuta Greek 31}, 
  term = {2021-31},
  langid = {greek},
%  language={langgreek},
    }   

@misc{testutha,
  title = {Test Titleut hilary}, 
  term = {2021-hilaryterm},
    }   
@misc{testuta,
  title = {Test Titleuta 31}, 
  term = {2021-31},
  author = {A Author},
  authorposition = {Adjunct Professor of Theoretics},
  university = {University of U},
  college = {College of C},
  school = {School of S},
  faculty = {Faculty of F},
  department = {Department of D},
  location = {Mars and The Moon and Mimas},
  image={example-image-a},
  sequence = {department,faculty,university,location,image},
  sequenceta = {title,term,author,authorposition},
    }   


@misc{testutb,
  title = {Test Titleutb 32}, 
  term = {2021-32},
  author = {zz},
  authorposition = {zz},
  university = {University of V},
  college = {College of D},
  school = {School of T},
  faculty = {Faculty of G},
  department = {Department of E},
  sequence = {department,college,university},
    }   
@misc{testutc,
  title = {Test Titleutc 33}, 
  term = {2021-33},
  courtlist = {Civil List},
  courtdivision = {Commercial Division},
  courtcourt = {Court of Appeal},
%  courtbench = {},
  courtname = {Supreme Court of XYZ},
  sequence = {courtlist,courtdivision,courtname},
    }   
@misc{testutd,
  title = {Test Titleutd 34}, 
  term = {2021-34},
%  courtlist = {},
%  courtdivision = {},
%  courtcourt = {},
  courtbench = {Full Court},
  courtname = {Supreme Court of XYZ},
  sequence = {courtbench,courtname},
    }   
@misc{testute,
  title = {Test Titleute 35}, 
  term = {2021-35},
    }   
@misc{testutf,
  title = {Test Titleutf 36}, 
  term = {2021-36},
    }   
@misc{testutg,
  title = {Test Titleutg 37}, 
  term = {2021-37},
    }   
    

@misc{testta,
  title = {Test Titleta 41}, 
  term = {2021-41},
    }   
@misc{testtb,
  title = {Test Titletb 42}, 
  term = {2021-42},
    }   
@misc{testtc,
  title = {Test Titletc 43}, 
  term = {2021-43},
    }   


@misc{testsa,
  title = {Test Titlesema 51}, 
  term = {2021-51},
    }   
@misc{testsb,
  title = {Test Titlesemb 52}, 
  term = {2021-52},
    }   
@misc{tests1,
  title = {Test Titlesem1 53}, 
  term = {2021-53},
    }   
@misc{tests2,
  title = {Test Titlesem2 54}, 
  term = {2021-54},
    }   


@misc{testsp,
  title = {Test Titlesp 61}, 
  term = {2021-61},
    }   
@misc{testsu,
  title = {Test Titlesu 62}, 
  term = {2021/2022-62},
    }   
@misc{testau,
  title = {Test Titleau 63}, 
  term = {2022-63},
    }   
@misc{testwi,
  title = {Test Titlewi 64}, 
  term = {2022-64},
    }   
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{term.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{term,
  authorposition,
  university,
  college,
  school,
  faculty,
  department,
  courtlist,
  courtdivision,
  courtcourt,
  courtname,
  courtbench,  
  image,
}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, format=xsv, datatype=literal]{sequence,
sequenceta,
}

%\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=literal]{location,
%}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{term,
  authorposition,
  university,
  college,
  school,
  faculty,
  department,
  sequence,
  courtlist,
  courtdivision,
  courtcourt,
  courtname,
  courtbench,
  sequenceta,
%  location,
 image,
  }

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}
          [Color=DarkGreen ,
          ]{Noto Serif}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\ExplSyntaxOn




%term
\DeclareDocumentCommand { \fcompareb } { m } 
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { - }  \l_my_tl 
\seq_get_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_myright_tlv
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 31 } { \bibstring{hilaryterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 32 } { \bibstring{epiphanyterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 33 } { \bibstring{lentterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 34 } { \bibstring{candlemasterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 35 } { \bibstring{easterterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 36 } { \bibstring{trinityterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 37 } { \bibstring{michaelmasterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 41 } { \bibstring{firstterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 42 } { \bibstring{secondterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 43 } { \bibstring{thirdterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 51 } { \bibstring{firstsemester} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 52 } { \bibstring{secondsemester} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 53 } { \bibstring{semesterone} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 54 } { \bibstring{semestertwo} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 61 } { \bibstring{springterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 62 } { \bibstring{summerterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 63 } { \bibstring{autumnterm} }
\int_compare:nNnT { \l_myright_tlv } = { 64 } { \bibstring{winterterm} }
}

%year
\DeclareDocumentCommand { \fcomparec } { m } 
{
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { - }  \l_my_tl 
\seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_myleft_tlv
\tl_use:N \l_myleft_tlv 

}




\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage[style=authoryear,
dateabbrev=false,% full name of season
language=autocite,%pick up the langid language, for citations
autolang=other,%wrap with otherlanguage environment and translate date-related names according to the langid
datamodel=term,
]{biblatex}


\NewBibliographyString{hilaryterm,
  epiphanyterm,
  lentterm,
  candlemasterm,
  easterterm,
  trinityterm,
  michaelmasterm,
  firstterm,
  secondterm,
  thirdterm,
  firstsemester,
  secondsemester,
  semesterone,
  semestertwo,
  springterm,
  summerterm,
  autumnterm,
  winterterm,
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
% 30
  hilaryterm = {Hilary Term},% jan-mar/apr
  epiphanyterm = {Epiphany Term},
  lentterm    = {Lent Term},%feb-apr
  candlemasterm = {Candlemas Term},
  easterterm = {Easter Term},%apr-may
  trinityterm = {Trinity Term},% apr-jun/jun-jul
  michaelmasterm = {Michaelmas Term},% oct-dec
%  40
  firstterm  = {First Term},
  secondterm  = {Second Term},
  thirdterm  = {Third Term},
% 50
  firstsemester   = {First Semester},
  secondsemester   = {Second Semester},
  semesterone   = {Semester One},
  semestertwo   = {Semester Two},
% 60
  springterm = {Spring Term},
  summerterm = {Summer Term},
  autumnterm = {Autumn Term},
  winterterm = {Winter Term},
}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\insertpic[1]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}}

%==============================
\newcommand\seqsep{\addcomma\addspace}
\newcommand\myseq[1]{\seqsep%
\ifstrequal{#1}{location}{\printlist{location}}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{author}{\printnames[authorrev]{#1}}{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{image}{\usefield{\insertpic}{image}}{%\usefield{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]}{image}
\ifstrequal{#1}{term}{\printterm}{\printfield{#1}}%
}}}%
}



\DeclareFieldFormat{sequence}{
    \forcsvfield{\myseq}{sequence}
}   
%
\newcounter{seqtacounter}
\newcommand\seqtazero{\setcounter{seqtacounter}{0}}
\newcommand\seqtastep{\stepcounter{seqtacounter}}

%title author
\newcommand\seqsepta{\addcomma\addspace}

\newcommand\myseqta[1]{%
\seqtastep%
\ifnum\value{seqtacounter}=1\relax\else\seqsepta\fi%
\ifstrequal{#1}{location}{\printlist{location}}{}%
\ifstrequal{#1}{author}{\printnames[authorrev]{#1}}{}%
\ifstrequal{#1}{term}{\printterm}{\printfield{#1}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{sequenceta}{
    \seqtazero
    \forcsvfield{\myseqta}{sequenceta}
}

%
\DeclareListFormat{language}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}\addcolon}{#1}}



\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasonall}
{}
{\textmd{\printlist{language}}
\printfield{title}\addcomma\addspace
\printdate}
{}
{}

\newcommand\uuformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\cuformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\suformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\fuformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\duformat[1]{#1}

\newcommand\postuuformat{}
\newcommand\postcuformat{}
\newcommand\postsuformat{}
\newcommand\postfuformat{}
\newcommand\postduformat{}


%  courtlist,
%  courtdivision,
%  courtcourt,
%  courtname,
%  courtbench,
\newcommand\lcformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\dcformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\ccformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\ncformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\bcformat[1]{#1}

\newcommand\postlcformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\postdcformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\postccformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\postncformat[1]{#1}
\newcommand\postbcformat[1]{#1}



\DeclareFieldFormat{plain}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{plainb}{\fcompareb{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{plainc}{\fcomparec{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{authorposition}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{university}{\uuformat{#1}\postuuformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{college}{\cuformat{#1}\postcuformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{school}{\suformat{#1}\postsuformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{faculty}{\fuformat{#1}\postfuformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{department}{\duformat{#1}\postduformat}

%
%  courtlist,
%  courtdivision,
%  courtcourt,
%  courtname,
%  courtbench,
\DeclareFieldFormat{courtlist}{\lcformat{#1}\postlcformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{courtdivision}{\dcformat{#1}\postdcformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{courtcourt}{\ccformat{#1}\postccformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{courtname}{\ncformat{#1}\postncformat}
\DeclareFieldFormat{courtbench}{\bcformat{#1}\postbcformat}


\newcommand\printterm{\seqsepta\printfield[plainb]{term}
\addcomma\addspace\printfield[plainc]{term}}


\DeclareNameFormat{authorrev}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
{\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{%
 \namepartgiven\space}\namepartfamily}%
{\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\space
 }%
\namepartfamily}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
{\addcomma\space}
{}}



\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasonallx}
{}
{\textmd{\printlist{language}}%
\iffieldundef{sequenceta}{%true
   \printfield{title}%
   \iffieldundef{term}{}{%
        \printterm}}{%false
   \printfield{sequenceta}%
   }%
\iffieldundef{sequence}{}{\printfield{sequence}}
}
{}
{}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasontitle}
{}
{\printfield{title}
}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseason}
{}
{\printdate}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasonterm}
{}
{\printfield[plainb]{term}}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeseasontermyear}
{}
{\printfield[plainc]{term}}
{}
{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{greek}{%
  spring    = {άνοιξη},
  summer  = {καλοκαίρι},
  autumn   = {φθινόπωρο},
  winter     = {χειμώνας},
  langgreek = {Ελληνικά},
  hilaryterm = {Ελληνικά Greek Hilary},
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  spring    = {primavera},
  summer  = {estate},
  autumn   = {autunno},
  winter     = {inverno},
  langitalian = {italiano},
}




%-----------------------------

\title{\citeseasontitle{notesset1}}
\author{}
\date{\citeseason{notesset1}}
%------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Overview}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset1}} covers introductory material.
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset2}} advances to the next topic.
\item \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset3}} covers the extended course.
\item German: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset4}} is the xyz version. 
\item Greek: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset5}} is the abc version. 
\item Italian: \textbf{\citeseasonall{notesset5a}} is the abc version. 
\end{itemize}


\section*{Season Extended}
\subsection*{University Terms and Court Terms}
%\citeseasonallx{testutha}\par
\citeseasonallx{testuta}.  \citeseasonterm{testuta} of \citeseasontermyear{testuta} will see a new\ldots\par
%
\renewcommand\seqsep{\ \\ \makebox[2em]{\ }}
\renewcommand\uuformat[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand\postuuformat{$\leftarrow$\par}
\noindent\citeseasonallx{testutb} xxx\par
\citeseasonallx{testutc}\par
\citeseasonallx{testutd}\par
\citeseasonallx{testute}\par
\citeseasonallx{testutf}\par\ 
\citeseasonallx{testutg}\par
\subsection*{Semesters}
\ \par
\citeseasonallx{testsa}\par
\citeseasonallx{testsb}\par
\citeseasonallx{tests1}\par
\citeseasonallx{tests2}\par
\subsection*{School Terms}
\ \par
\citeseasonallx{testta}, the \citeseasonterm{testta} of \citeseasontermyear{testta}\par
\citeseasonallx{testtb}\par
\citeseasonallx{testtc}\par
\ \par
\citeseasonallx{testsp}\par
\citeseasonallx{testsu}\par
\citeseasonallx{testau}\par
\citeseasonallx{testwi}\par

\section*{Languages}
\citeseasonallx{testutag}\par


%biber
%
%format.pm
%
%\begin{verbatim}
%  my %
%    seasons = ( 21 => 'spring',
%                  22 => 'summer',
%                  23 => 'autumn',
%                  24 => 'winter' );
%                  
%...\texlive\2020
%\texmf-dist
%\source
%\bibtex
%\biber
%\biblatex-biber.tar
%\biblatex-biber
%\biblatex-biber-2.15
%\lib
%\Biber
%\Date                  
%\end{verbatim}

\renewcommand\seqsepta{\par}
\renewcommand\seqsep{\par}
\renewcommand\uuformat[1]{$\rightarrow$\begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline\textsc{#1}\\ \hline \end{tabular}}
\renewcommand\postuuformat{}

\citeseasonallx{testuta}\par\bigskip 
\renewcommand\seqsepta{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand\seqsep{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand\uuformat[1]{#1}
\citeseasonallx{testutb}

\end{document}
```

Compile with lualatex in a recent TexLive because `babel` uses lua code for language/script processing.