# How to print the current season automatically?

Tags: date

I know we can print the current year by \the\year. How about the reasons? I live in north hemisphere, so the definition of the four seasons at here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season#Meteorological works for me.

Comment: The exact date for season change varies from one year to the other.  Also depends on the hemisphere you are on.  Depending on your exact requirements you can use the current date to compute it.  Can you clarify, please?

Comment: Can you define what your seasons are?

Comment: Thanks guys. I edited my question. So unlike year, I would have to manually compute it? I was thinking maybe the computer can automatically detect where I am.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292600/134144 appears to be related.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, it does! Didn't find this post.

Comment: @leandriis Useful link. Added a (basic) generalised `biblatex` solution for completeness to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292600/how-to-print-spring-if-in-month-is-in-jan-june-otherwise-fall/568130#568130 as it deals with published material (lectures).